# Allowing the user to choose a new font from a list on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, uikit

I have a text field where I would like the user to be able to set the font from a drop down box. I can't seem to find any documentation related to doing anything like this, but it seems like something that should be fairly trivial so I assume I'm just using poor search terms or something.

I can obviously build the drop down box myself, but I have no idea how to get a list of all available fonts prefrably including my own custom fonts.

Comment: I'm not sure why my answer was down-voted, but I'd definitely suggest you check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of fonts to populate your drop-down list like so:

```
self.fontNameList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
for (NSString *familyName in familyNames) {
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for (NSString *fontName in fontNames) {
       [self.fontNameList addObject:fontName];
    }
}
// And optionally, to arrange them in alphabetical order...
[self.fontNameList sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

This should find *all* your fonts, custom and otherwise.

Then assuming you're using a `UITableView` for your drop-down menu where each row contains a font name, once an index is selected you can set the font in your `UITableViewDelegate`'s `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method like so:

```
UIFont *currentFont = [UIFont fontWithName:[self.fontNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] size:12];
```

I've set the size to 12 in this case, but you can set it to whatever variable float value or default constant float you desire.

Comment: This seems like a solid solution, I would also like to know why it's being down voted.

Comment: @Tiddly Just checked and this code works. Yeah, I tend to get some suspicious downvotes several times a day after two guys on the site didn't like a question I gave a *month* ago haha... It doesn't bother me personally (I'm not here for "points"), but it's not so great for others if they see my answer right after it's been downvoted for the wrong reasons then don't look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

Fist get the font families with [familyNames](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/familyNames) then get all the fonts for the different family names with [fontNamesForFamilyName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontNamesForFamilyName:).

Show the names and react on the users selection by setting the selected font.